# Tableauserver connection with python on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, tableau-api, tsc

!pip install tableauserverclient !pip install -U requests[security] import requests tableau_auth=TSC.TableauAuth('MAKPythonTab','xPK2QpkVTVegTv3PNQXB4w==:10S2NeLO4bkFB2iaZQJ8tKVEpTjINotG',site_id='home') server=TSC.Server('https://tableau-it.homedepot.com',use_server_version=False) requests.get('https://tableau-it.homedepot.com', verify=False) server.add_http_options({'verify':False}) with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth): all_datasources,pagination_item=server.datasources.get() datasource_ids=[datasource.id for datasource in all_datasources] print("\nThere are {} datasources on site".format(len(all_datasources))) for i in datasource_ids: if file_download.lower().endswith('.tdsx'): file_download =server.datasources.download(id) print(file_download) server.auth.sign_out()

I am trying to connect the above tableau server but unfortunately getting error named Expat error & NonXMLResponseError. Anyone please help me on this..

Please give me a solution to run this code successfully.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your code as it's unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

How about running an opensource alternative to Tableau in juypter cell directly: https://github.com/Kanaries/pygwalker

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).